# STD library iterator that never ends?

Tags: c++, string, iterator

Is there a string buffer class that provides an iterator that allocates a new buffer if necessary on incrementing (`*++itr = 'x'`), or am I stuck with pre-allocating buffers first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is something called [`std::back_inserter()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter), which calls `push_back()` every time you assign to it. Some example code:

```
int main() {
    string s = "abc";
    auto it = std::back_inserter(s);
    it = 'd';
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Will print out: `abcd`

Comment: for non-C++11 the type you need to use instead of `auto` is `std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>`.   Also, `#include <iterator>` may be required.

Comment: It's arguably more consistent with other iterator semantics to use `*it++ = 'd';`, but works either way....

Comment: Insertion iterators are a bit weird; `*it` just resolves to `it`; and `++` is a no-op

Comment: @MattMcNabb: this can be argued to be an implementation detail, I would favor consistency in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::ostringstream` with `std::ostream_inserter`, something like this (untested):

```
std:::ostringstream stream;
auto itr = ostream_inserter<char>(stream);
```